# Convert Javascript Object keys to strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I have the following Javascript Object.

```
{min: 0.01, max: 0.02, 29%: 0.03, 31%: 0.04, 32%: 0.05}
```

How can I transform it to an object with the keys as string. For example:

```
{'min': 0.01, 'max': 0.02, '29%': 0.03, '31%': 0.04, '32%': 0.05}
```

The reason I need it in this format is because [NoUISlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-values/) use it for custom values.

When inserting the values manually, I've created a `var range = {}`  and assigned values like so:

```
range = [percent + '%'] = some_decimal_value; // percent is an integer
```

NoUiSlider doesn't accept an object like the first one, so I need to convert it to an object with keys as string.

I've tried `range[String(percent + '%')], didn't work.`

See 'snapping between steps' how the object should be [here](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-values/).

When I change the value or the range variable to this:

```
range = {
    'min': 0,
    '10%': 50,
    '20%': 100,
    '30%': 150,
    '40%': 500,
    '50%': 800,
    'max': 1000
}
```

It works.

Thanks.

Comment: Every key in a plain Javascript object *is* a string. The "object" at the top of your question is not valid Javascript. So, where those data come from?

Comment: @MaxArt ok, I assume that the key is in string and I just see it in Chrome as non-string. If so, what does the object doesn't work with NoUiSlider and the one that I shown in the question does? Thanks

Comment: @IdanShechter are you sure the issue here isn't that you're using float values rather than int values within your object?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly yes, this is the issue! - it's stuck on zero all the time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with NoUISlider - your current object is simply invalid. You cannot have `%` symbols in object key names without them being wrapped in quotes in the first place.

As it currently stands, your JavaScript is throwing the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token `%`

The only thing you can do here is modify where this object is generated in the first place - your JavaScript will be throwing errors here anyway, so check your browser's [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) for where this happens.

---

> The object is valid as I initialized it in code because I can see it in the inspector correctly, at least in the way I initialized it like [percent + '%'] –  [Idan Shechter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/865939/idan-shechter) [2 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26504538/convert-javascript-object-keys-to-strings/26504605?noredirect=1#comment41640412_26504605)

If that is the case then your object keys are already in string form. In JavaScript, when you add a Number value to a String value it *concatenates* the two values into one String value:

```
1 + '%'
```

```
-> "1%"

var foo = {};
foo[30 + '%'] = 'bar';
```

```
-> Object {30%: "bar"}
```

The JavaScript console may display this as `30%` (not wrapped in quotes), but if we check its type we'll see that it is actually a string:

```
for (var key in foo)
    console.log(typeof key);
```

```
-> string
```

---

Your question states that doing it without float values works fine, but doing it with float values doesn't, so I think the real issue here may be that you're using float values rather than integer values when initialising your original object.

Comment: The object is valid as I initialized it in code because I can see it in the inspector correctly, at least in the way I initialized it like [percent + '%'].

Comment: @IdanShechter if you initialised it like that then your object is already in string form.

Comment: I understand that it's not an issue with the key as non-string, therefore I assume that the problem relies somewhere else. Thanks for the in-depth answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your original object *cannot exist* in the first place:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%'. Expected ':' after property name.
```

All your keys are automatically strings in javascript.

Comment: Hi, that's how the object looks in the chrome inspector

Comment: @IdanShechter Chrome inspector *always* shows key names without quotes. They can't be anything other than strings so there's no point in adding the quotes to signify strings.

Comment: @Juhana, so I assume that what I am doing is right and the object is valid. If so, why NoUiSlider doens't accept it (I updated the question with a object value that does work)

Comment: @IdanShechter Show **complete** code so that we can try the issue ourselves and see where the *actual* problem is.